# mod rewrite settings.php?id=5 to xml/5/settings.xml

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying load

```
settings.php?id=5
```

by accessing

```
xml/5/settings.xml
```

here is the code but its not working im just getting a 404 error:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+)\.php$ /%1/$1.xml [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your end user to enter `xml/5/settings.xml`, you have your rewrite *backwards*. On the left input side, you need to match the input URI:

This assumes `settings` is a dynamic value, which is captured in `$2`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^xml/([\d]+)/([a-z]+)\.xml$ $2.php?id=$1
```

If `settings` is a *static* value, hard code it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^xml/([\d]+)/settings.xml$ settings.php?id=$1
```